# MVC 4 C# Calendar Widget from Action-View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a web calendar using HTML,CSS and C# in an MVC application. The HTML is in a view and I have a controller with an action that initializes the Calendar and displays the correct days on the view.

It works as intended but the problem comes from the fact that I want to embed this calendar to a couple of pages in unrelated Views controlled by different actions and with different models loaded.

I could copy paste the view code and make the necessary adjustments to the model but that would not be ideal. I tried with `RenderAction` but the problem is that when I use the buttons to navigate to different months I leave the initial view. e.g.:

```
@Html.ActionLink("‹", "Calendar", 
new { month = Model.RequestedDateTime.Month - 1, year = 
Model.RequestedDateTime.Year })
```

Is there a way to modify this behavior?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in a similar way, to what developer10214 proposed. I used a div and in that I used `Render.Action`. Then I used the following code

```
 $(function () {
 $("#cal").on('click', "#backwards", function () {
 $.ajax({
    url: "Home/Calendar?target=backwards",
    cache:false,
    type: "GET",
    success: function (result) {
        $("#cal").html(result);
    }
});
});
});
```

in the including page. And I did not use ActionLink at all.

Answer (score 1):

Html.ActionLink, alway creates a normal link, with have the common behaviour. If you want to share your calender.
To avoid redundant code, you may redesign the calender as a partial view and replace the link by a label for example. Bind an ajax function to the label-click-event to refresh the calender. Something like:

```
@Html.Label("<", new { onclick="pageMonthBack("+Model.RequestedDateTime.Month - 1+", " Model.RequestedDateTime.Year+");" })
```

I would place the called ajax functions in a script which is loaded separately.